# Ruby - rejecting hashes that are nested within arrays

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to reject specific hashes from within an array. I'm getting confused due to the nesting of things

I have a hash that looks like this

```
hash = {
  "key1":
  [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "key2":
  [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "id": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to iterate over each of the values and modify the arrays to reject any hash that has `hash[:name] == "bar"` and still keep everything else intact.

I'm trying

```
hash = hash.each_value do |value|
  value.reject {|v| v[:name] == "bar"}
end
=> {:key1=>[{:name=>"foo", :id=>1}, {:name=>"foo", :id=>2}, {:name=>"bar", :id=>3}],
 :key2=>[{:name=>"foo", :id=>1}, {:name=>"foo", :id=>2}, {:name=>"bar", :id=>3}]}
```

I can remove them with something like this:

```
hash.values.flatten.reject {|v| v[:name] == "bar"}
=> [{:name=>"foo", :id=>1}, {:name=>"foo", :id=>2}, {:name=>"foo", :id=>1}, {:name=>"foo", :id=>2}]
```

But I need the initial hash to remain intact

I expect to derive this:

```
hash = {
  "key1":
  [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 2
    }
  ],
  "key2":
  [
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "foo",
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also tried this route:

```
hash.reject do |key, value|
  value.each do |r|
    r[:name] == "bar"
  end
end

=> {}
```

Any help is much appreciated - I'm down for an explanation of where my logic is bad

I know that I'm iterating over things incorrectly, it's just a bit confusing to me with all the nesting

Comment: I think I just need to remove the extra array wrapper from `hash.values` and iterate over that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Schwern has identified the problems with your code so I will merely suggest a more Ruby-like solution.

```
hash = {
  "key1": [{ "name": "foo", "id": 1 },
           { "name": "foo", "id": 2 },
           { "name": "bar", "id": 3 }],
  "key2": [{ "name": "foo", "id": 1 },
           { "name": "foo", "id": 2 },
           { "name": "bar", "id": 3 }]
}
```

```
hash.transform_values { |arr| arr.reject { |h| h[:name] == "bar" } }
  #=> { "key1": [{ "name": "foo", "id": 1 },
  #              { "name": "foo", "id": 2 }],
  #     "key2": [{ "name": "foo", "id": 1 },
  #              { "name": "foo", "id": 2 }]
  #   }
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values). Note that `hash` is not mutated. To modify `hash` in place use [Hash#transform_values!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21).

Comment: `transform_values` is pretty handy for this. It'd be interesting to compare which of the `transform_values { |v| v.reject }` vs. `each_value { |v| v.reject! }` approach works best.

Comment: I don't know if it is any more or less "ruby-like" but I prefer this approach because I was unclear as to the intent base on these two statements, I view as contradictory. "modify the arrays" and "I need the initial hash to remain intact"

Comment: thank you :)

@engineersmnky sry, i didn't do well at communicating my intent. intent is to basically just filter out some of the hashes based on an expiry date. i'm transforming this data and want to reject anything that has a date from the past. I didn't realize i could use transform_values, which is what i ended up going with

Comment: @tadman i did end up using the `transform_values` method in a couple other places after this, i just wasn't aware of its existence, need to learn more methods

Comment: @magicfishy no need to apologize however if this answer solved your issue feel free to click the checkmark under the vote tally.

Answer (score 3):

You're not modifying the hash, but *the values in the hash*. `hash = hash.each_value` is doing nothing, (and the return value of `each_value` isn't documented).

`value.reject` does reject the values, but not in place. It returns a new array and leaves the original alone.

```
a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

# The modified array: ["foo", "baz"]
p a.reject { |v| v == "bar" }

# The original array is untouched: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
p a
```

Use `reject!` to modify each array in place.

```
hash.each_value do |value|
  value.reject! {|v| v[:name] == "bar"}
end
```